# Countable subsets of TVSs

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, topological-vector-spaces

This is something which is not clear to me. Take any countable subset $C$ of a compact set $K$ in a locally convex topological vector space $X$. Can we conclude that there is a point $x\in X$ such that $C\cup\{x\}$ is compact? I am mostly concerned with duals of Banach spaces equipped with the weak*-topology.

Comment: No, $\lbrace \frac1n - 1 \colon n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \rbrace \cup \lbrace 1-\frac1n \colon n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \rbrace$ needs two points to compactify. Generally, $C$ may be dense in $K$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Not true. You can compactify it with one point. Add a point $c$ and a neighbourhood of $c$ consists of all but finitely many of your points.

Comment: @Vobo Yes, if you ignore the ambient space, you can. But "Can we conclude that there is a point $x \in X$ such that $C \cup \{x\}$ is compact?" makes me almost certain the OP means "as a (topological, not linear) subspace of $X$".

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, probably you are right with a topological subspace of $X$. Let's wait for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Take compact $[0,1]$ and consider its rational points $Q$. You need to add uncountably many points to make $Q$ compact.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a topological space admits a one-point compactification, iff it is Hausdorff and locally compact. It is not difficult to see this, google for Alexandroff one-point compactification.